# How to access the value for text of a button upon pressing it. [KIVY]

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy, kivy-language

I am trying to access the value for text upon pressing a button in the python.

```
class MainScreen(Screen):
    def get_text_value():
        *something to get text value of button*        
    pass

<MainScreen>
  Button:
    text: 'Example'
    on_release: root.get_text_value()
```

In this example I would want to be able to access the string 'Example' from the Python.
The function get_text_value would return the string 'Example' if that makes sense.

Thank you very much for helping! It is greatly appreciated.

Comment: You can set the `id` for the button and use `self.root.ids.btn.text` or pass the value to the function `root.get_text_value(self.text)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass the text to the `get_text_value()` method by specifying it explicitly in the `kv`:

```
<MainScreen>
  Button:
    text: 'Example'
    on_release: root.get_text_value(self.text)  # pass text value
```

Then the `get_text_value()` method can be:

```
class MainScreen(Screen):
    def get_text_value(self, text):
        print('text:', text)
```

Comment: It works! Thank you so much for helping! I really appreciate you helping us out :)